# How to grab value that is being 'globbed' in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have code that concatenates two parts of a file path I am interested in disecting:

```
import glob

prefix = /aldo/programs/info
suffix = /final/*_cube/myFile.txt

prefix = prefix.rstrip()

file = glob.glob(prefix+'/final/*_cube/myFile.txt')

print (file)
```

Printing the final file gives me:

```
/aldo/programs/info/final/Michael_cube/myFile.txt
```

Which is GOOD and INTENDED. However, I am trying to set the string that was globbed, in this case, 'Michael' equal to a variable. I have tried using regular expressions but cannot find a way to grab the value (Michael) that was globbed. I am quite stuck and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `print(re.search("/([^/]*?)_cube","/aldo/programs/info/final/Michael_cube/myFile.txt").groups())`

Answer (score 2):

You can use string slicing, you got all the parts that you need to strip from the result to get what whas provided as `*`-value:

```
import glob

prefix = "/aldo/programs/info"
s0,g,s1 = "/final/", "*", "_cube/myFile.txt" # split the parts around the * 
suffix = s0+g+s1                             # and recombinate
prefix = prefix.rstrip()

file = glob.glob(prefix+'/final/*_cube/myFile.txt')

name = "/aldo/programs/info/final/Michael_cube/myFile.txt"

# slice: len(prefix+s0) starting and stopping at -len(s1)
print(name[len(prefix+s0):-len(s1)])
```

Output:

```
Michael
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kaz3Az/1)

`^.*?\/final\/(.*?)_cube\/myFile\.txt$`

You can either grab the contents from group 1, or replace the entire match with the substitution string `$1` to get the output.

Explanation:
starting and ending the patern with `^` and `$` requires the pattern to match the entire line. you can account for any unknowns in the data with "match all" quntifiers '.*?' and then all you need to do is grab the desired output with a capture groups.

Comment: But how does this line specifically read my 'file' variable? How does it know what it is reading from?

Comment: assuming `file` is a collection, you iterate over the collection and run the regex on each one, if not just pass it in.
`re.sub("^.*?\/final\/(.*?)_cube\/myFile\.txt$", "\\1", file)`